# Finding and comparing the minimum timedelta of 2 datetime lists python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timedelta

I have 2 lists containing **datetime.timedelta** values.
Need help finding the minimum of both lists and comparing them to find out which is greater.

Note: I am fairly new to Python

This is the first list, extracting datetime values from dicts v,w:

```
for y in range(len(v)):
    try:
            gap.append(v[y]-w[y])
    except:
            print "End of list"
```

And this is the second list, calculating intervals within dict values:

```
for y in range(len(v)):
    try:
            comp.append(v[y]-v[y+1])
    except:
            print "End of list"
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
if min(comp)<min(gap):
    print "Anomaly detected"
else:
    print "Looks good"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use max and min to find out

```
w = [datetime.timedelta(10), datetime.timedelta(9), datetime.timedelta(0)]
v = [datetime.timedelta(11), datetime.timedelta(12), datetime.timedelta(13)]
max(min(v),min(w))

datetime.timedelta(11)
```